# Latitude and Latitude (location name) Upload a file or image from ionic 4 whit angular 7?

Tags: angular7, ionic4

How to get file properties should be GPS(latitude and longitude or location name) and upload a file or image from ionic 4?

Answer (score 0):

This is not really the point of StackOverflow, you are supposed to post when you got stuck, not just request tutorials to be custom written for you.

You have also requested two separate tutorials, and the second one is not clearly defined.

I'll try to help though.

To get latitude and longitude you need to read the EXIF data of an image. There are libraries out there and there are guides that show how to use them to calculate the lat/lon info:

- https://awik.io/extract-gps-location-exif-data-photos-using-javascript/

For the uploading a file or image then you might find this tutorial helpful to learn the basics:

- https://devdactic.com/ionic-4-image-upload-storage/

But that is just a simple example and you will quickly realise you need more complicated code to secure it and multiple servers to deploy it to, and then there are scaling issues and cdn's and more to think about. This is when people generally turn to something like Firebase Storage which will let you push files into the cloud and gives you all the structure without having to write it. Start here for a tutorial that explains these concepts:

- https://blog.smartcodehub.com/how-to-upload-an-image-to-firebase-from-an-ionic-4-app/